# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a new Konsole tab?

Tags: kde, konsole

I want to open a new Konsole tab with my keyboard. Is there a shortcut for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have to create a custom global shortcut from the system settings for the kubuntu.

Comment: don't work on Plasma on Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you checked the Keyboard Shortcuts in KDE System Settings?

Comment: yes, i checked all the shortcuts that are mapped in KDe's keyboard-settings. nothing was there.

Answer (score 38):

Works for me (in Kubuntu):

System Settings -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Custom Shortcuts -> right-click -> New -> Global Shortcut -> Command/URL -> type a name (i.e. "Terminal" or "Konsole") -> choose tab "Trigger" -> click on None -> press Ctrl+Shift+T -> choose tab "Action" -> enter "konsole" for Command/URL -> apply

By default this combination (Ctrl + Shift + T) works in Ubuntu, but not in Kubuntu.

Comment: for me it's not working. I've also tried another combination, not ctrl+shift+t but still no luck.  Kubuntu 15 plasma 5.5

Comment: is it possible to enter a command into the opened terminal with this setting?

Comment: Works by default on `Kubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 22):

In Plasma, the shorcut is disabled by default in example custom shorcuts:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I assigned a shortcut to open the terminal (Konsole) demonstrated:

1. Right-click on the **Kickoff Application Launcher** icon (in the left bottom corner of Desktop scene)
2. Hit on **Edit Applications...**
3. Expand **System**
4. Hit on **Konsole (Terminal)**
5. In right-side click on **Advanced** Tab
6. In **Current Shortcut Key** set a new shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Try it.

Answer (score 1):

While adding a keyboard shortkut in the settings is the solution to your answer, I suggest a better solution than opening a new konsole every time:

Install yakuake:

```
sudo apt install yakuake
```

It has a global keyboard shortcut that is conigured at first start and it keeps your session with multiple terminal windows open in the background all the time.

Comment: Here's how to avoid opening a new Konsole every time: once you've launched it, you can [press Super+0/1/2/etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813262/which-desktop-environments-allow-switching-among-windows-with-supernumbers), depending on which number the Konsole tab is in the tab bar.