# Which desktop environments allow switching among windows with Super+<numbers>?

Tags: shortcut-keys, desktop-environments

Aside from Unity, which of the [many desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) support switching among the currently open windows using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>/.../<kbd>9</kbd>?

### Reasoning

This is especially handy if you often switch among the same few apps, e.g. a browser, a file manager and an editor, but also have other apps open, so Alt+Tabbing to the desired window would take more time.<sup>1</sup>

That keyboard shortcut saves me probably 5 seconds per minute on the average, so ~40 minutes a day, and it's supported by Windows 7 as well. Adding custom keyboard shortcuts for the app doesn't work, because pressing the shortcut will launch a new instance of the app.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1. The DE will order the most frequently used windows first, but you have to first look and see how many times you have to press Alt+Tab; while with Super+1 or Super+2, you always know which shortcut goes to one app or the other.</sup>

<sup>2. Some apps have an option to allow only one instance, but this is the exception rather than the rule, and even in that case, there will be a noticeable flicker of launching the new instance and seeing it exiting immediately.</sup>

Comment: You can write a script using wmctrl, see my [blog post](http://www.mreq.eu/2013/06/lightning-fast-window-switching-in-ubuntu/). Also there are wrappers such as my [wmctile](https://github.com/mreq/wmctile).

Comment: You can easily do it with Unity and XFCE but preventing multiple instances of an application depends solely to the applications' code. You will have to put together a script that could do that. A mild solution would be to use Alt+Tab and before releasing, use the mouse to select the desired application.

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis: using the mouse is totally out of the question if you want any productivity gains. In Unity, the application code doesn't need to support anything - the shortcut simply gives focus to the window (I think that's called "raise"); it doesn't launch the app again.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I see. So, until now Unity is the only option. I'm running XFCE and while pressing the key combination of the -already running- desired app, it spawns a new instance.

Comment: I think I may have an idea for a script that can sort of do what you want . . .  As Dan pointed out in his answer , in Unity you can switch to a program by using `Super + num` shortcut only if the program is running. If you want, i could write a shortcut that reorganizes the launcher in such way that you can use `Super+number` starting from 1,2,3 to N. Let me know if this is something that you would be interested in.

Comment: Just noticed that you're both author of the question and the answer. In any case, my proposal stands

Comment: @Serg: I'd love to have a script to enable Super+num for Cinnamon.

Comment: With a little help, XFCE does: http://askubuntu.com/questions/557084/any-way-to-open-windows-from-the-windows-bar-using-a-shortcut. Actually all doe :)

Comment: If you end up on an env that doesn't support it, consider [jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Desktop environments supporting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>

These support task switching via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> out of the box, and require (almost) no configuration.

### KDE Plasma

[This was implemented in Plasma 5.9](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336348). You still need to uncheck "Keep launchers separate" in the Task Manager Settings to preserve the 1..9 order, otherwise the numbers will be reassigned as you close/open the applications.

### GNOME 3 (Ubuntu 20)

GNOME [implemented <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> app switching](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/merge_requests/370) in Jan 2019. Here's a screenshot of GNOME 3 in Ubuntu 20:

[image: GNOME 3]

### Ubuntu 18 GNOME

Ubuntu's [tweaked](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/05/ubuntu-18-04-the-return-of-a-familiar-interface-marks-the-best-ubuntu-in-years/) version of GNOME supports <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>, with one annoyance: when switching to an application with more than one window (often the case with Chrome/Firefox), you [have to further choose which of the windows to switch to](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1813385).

### Unity (Ubuntu 16)

Supports the key combo by default. If the app is running, Unity will switch to it. If it isn't, it will be launched.

[image: Unity]

### Linux Mint Cinnamon

As of version 20, Cinnamon supports <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> for the "Modern" panel layout.

[image: Cinnamon "modern" Panel Layout]

The feature isn't very discoverable because Cinnamon doesn't show any number tooltips over the taskbar icons when you press <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Note that the feature was tricky enough to take years to implement after it was first [requested in 2015](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/3883), then [by myself in 2016](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/5561).

### DEs with support via extensions/plugins/applets

Note that letting plugin authors build such a feature is fraught with problems. In several years, I haven't found *any* plugin/extension/macro/whatever that gets this right. This sort of feature needs to be well-integrated into the window manager, and this was confirmed by one of the authors of MATE Desktop, who [agreed with me](https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco/issues/283#issuecomment-371380179).

### DEs that don't support <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> out of the box

- [LXDE](https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=39971) as of Jan 2021
- [Budgie](https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/super-number-keyboard-shortcut/1040) as of Oct 2020
- [MATE](https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco/issues/283) as of Dec 2018
- [GNOME 2/3](https://superuser.com/questions/614792/how-to-enable-windows-key-number-in-gnome-to-switch-to-a-window-in-the-taskbar); official [confirmation from GNOME developer](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/937#note_419817)
- [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813262/which-desktop-environments-allow-switching-among-windows-with-supernumbers/813575#comment1230864_813262)

Comment: Just to clarify: XFCE does support Super+number key combination for applications out-of-the-box but if the application is running it doesn't switch to it, but prefers to spawn another instance.

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis: I'm curious what the point of that could potentially be; why choose to launch a new instance of the very same apps over an over, instead of switching to them? Sounds more like a half-baked feature or a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, rather a simple function designed without productivity in mind, or else it would have an option to choose your preferred way. Also there is a fair amount of users that prefer this way due to the nature of their work done. By the way I think you should have a look at this [run-or-raise application](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp). I think it does what you want for any X11 desktop.

Comment: And for some weird way I can't mention your name with @, even if I type it, it disappears on save. (missed the 5min edit window on previous comment -.-)

Comment: The DE will order the most frequently used windows first <---

In Unity, you can easily order apps by locking them to Launcher.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 (Ubunut Gnome, not vanilla) with Appkeys extension restores Super-<num> switching behaviour as it was in Unity. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/